# How do I fix Dell Lat. D630 Laptop clock gains 5 hours coming out of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS back to Win 7 Pro?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, mate

Installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS alongside Win 7 Pro last night and both times I have rebooted to Windows 7 the clock has been ~ 5 hours fast. The clock indicates correctly in Ubuntu and I selected the Central Time Zone during the Ubuntu setup. Is there a permanent way to correct this beyond resetting the clock continuously?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows expects the hardware clock to be localtime, and Ubuntu expects it to be UTC.

It's normally better to configure windows to also use UTC.

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time)

On Windows, create a file named `utc.reg` with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

Double-click it and reboot.